# Advice upon class variables in PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am getting an error displayed in calling my `$dog2` method `greet()` that is undefined variable but I can't understand where I am making a mistake. Please help me :)

```
 <?php

        class Dog{

            public $numLegs=4;

            public $name;

            public function __construct($name){

                $this->name=$name;

            }

            public function bark(){

                return "woof";

            }

            public function greet(){

                return $name." is very beatifull dog hmmm";

            }

        }

        $dog1= new Dog("Barker");

        $dog2= new Dog("Amigo");

        echo $dog1->bark();

        echo $dog2->greet();


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant direcly access name like `$name` you have to use    `$this->name`

change the following line

```
 return $this->name." is very beatifull dog hmmm";
```

`$this->name` refers to the current class's variable name, When using `$this->name`, you are accessing the property with the name name of the current object.